# Правильно ли я спроектировал связи между таблицами?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть 3 таблицы:

parsers

```
parsers
-id
-name
-created_at
```

parsers_settings

```
parsers_settings
-id
-parser_id
-some_config_field
```

и к примеру amazon_parser_products

```
amazon_parser_products
-id
-amazon_product_id
-name
```

Мне нужно как-то сохранять информацию о выполнении каждого парсера и привязывать товары с таблицы "amazon_parser_products" к выполнению , чтобы знать когда и при каком выполнении товары были добавлены с парсера . Есть вариант добавить таблицу

```
parsers_executions
-id
-status
-finished_at
```

И тогда amazon_parser_products добавить еще одно поле

```
amazon_parser_products
-id
-execution_id
-amazon_product_id
-name
```

Норм так делать? или есть лучшие варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы получиь наиболее корректный ответ вам стоило бы описать все в процессах и сущностя - это дало бы более ясную картину для составления подходящих таблиц.

Исходя из того что вы описали, я бы рекомендовал вам хранить данные в следующем виде:

```
parsers
 - id
 - name
 - type
 - created
```

Парсеры, с указанием типов парсеров

```
parser_settings
 - id
 - parser_id
 - some_config_field
```

Настройки парсеров

```
products
 - id
 - product_type
 - external_id
 - name
```

Продукты, с указанием типа продукта и внешнего идентификатора. Все импортируемые продукты стоит приводить к одному типу (+- несколько полей можно оставлять пустыми для типов где такие данные отсутвуют, но не стоит гнаться за поддрежанием обсалютно всех типов). Иначе можете утонуть в множетсве различных типов, что привед к невозможности использования изоморфизма и необходимости написания всего кода повторно для каждого типа.

```
executions
 - id
 - status
 - finished_at
```

Задачи импорта

```
products_to_executions
 - product_id
 - execution_id
```

Соотношения импортированных товар и задач, в рамках которых они были импортированы. Стоит хранить в отдельной таблице, так как взаимоотношение сущностей Товар и Задача - многие к многим

Comment: спасибо за ответ . смотри, в таблице "products" хранятся товары со всех парсеров . разве хранить товары с каждого парсера в отдельной таблицы не было бы правильнее ? т.е. отдельный сайт = отдельная таблица

Comment: @KolyaVantukh А что вы потом будете делать с товарами ? Если они будут в отдельных таблицах, то вы например не сможете одним запросом получить полный перечень товаров в БД. А для хранения нестандартных атрибутов можно завести поле типа JSON или использовать EAV структуру (в зависимости от потребностей по работе с ними)

Comment: @KolyaVantukh как я и описал выше, таким образом вы потеряете возможности полиморфизма. Например, если вы зохотить вывести список всех импортироанных товаром, то 
1) вы не сможете одним запросом взять их из базы, придется делать по отдельному запросу в каждую таблицу. 
2) Запросив разные товары из разных таблиц, вам прийдется в памяти хранить их в разных массивах, и обрабатывать по отдельности, так как они будут иметь разные типы (то есть разный набор полей)
3) Вы не сможете легко их отсортировать, только по раздельности
Поэтому лучше приводить все типы к одному виду.